Using wru, the function predict_race gives me an "Error in tmp[[1]] : subscript out of bounds" when I use the census.geo
Using the very basic code and example from the Readme file, I get "Error in tmp[[1]] : subscript out of bounds".  Any insight why?
Note that the 4th line, with the option surname.only=TRUE works fine, and my Census key is also working.
My code:
library(wru)

CENSUS_API_KEY<-'My_own_key'

Voterfile <- readr::read_csv("test.csv")
predict_race(voter.file = Voterfile, surname.only = TRUE)

predict_race(voter.file = Voterfile, census.geo = "tract", census.key=CENSUS_API_KEY, party = "PID")

The last line Error
predict_race(voter.file = Voterfile, census.geo = "tract", census.key=CENSUS_API_KEY, party = "PID")
Predicting race for 2020
Collecting 2020 Census data...
Error in tmp[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Playing with options, it seems related to calling up the census.geo.
I tried Surname only and it works (ie. it provides the probability for the 10 people in the data file.
I tried census.geo = "county" and didn't work.
I tried to remove unnecessary data in the file and it didn't work.

dput(head(Voterfile, n = 10))
structure(list(VoterID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), surname = c("Khanna", 
"Imai", "Rivera", "Fifield", "Zhou", "Ratkovic", "Johnson", "Lopez", 
"Wantchekon", "Morse"), state = c("NJ", "NJ", "NY", "NJ", "NJ", 
"NJ", "NY", "NJ", "NJ", "DC"), CD = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
9, 12, 12, 0), county = c(21, 21, 61, 21, 21, 21, 61, 21, 21, 
1), tract = c(4000, 4501, 4800, 4501, 4501, 4000, 14900, 4501, 
4501, 1301), block = c(3001, 1025, 6001, 1025, 1025, 1025, 4000, 
1025, 1025, 3005), age = c(29, 40, 33, 27, 28, 35, 25, 33, 50, 
29), sex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), party = c("Ind", 
"Dem", "Rep", "Dem", "Dem", "Ind", "Dem", "Rep", "Rep", "Rep"
), PID = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2), place = c(74000, 60900, 
51000, 60900, 60900, 60900, 51000, 60900, 60900, 50000), pred.whi = c(0.021711601, 
0.015364583, 0.092415538, 0.854810748, 0.001548762, 0.852374629, 
0.831282563, 0.062022518, 0.396500218, 0.861168219), pred.bla = c(0.000955265, 
0.000232082, 0.004709997, 0.001087074, 0.000182351, 0.005259059, 
0.061324255, 0.00466914, 0.139072288, 0.04984491), pred.his = c(0.00283, 
0.00902, 0.786, 0.0178, 7.03e-05, 0.00809, 0.0106, 0.822, 0.268, 
0.0113), pred.asi = c(0.93364592, 0.90245186, 0.09924761, 0.04546436, 
0.99501901, 0.02529163, 0.01602557, 0.08321206, 0.11018413, 0.01633532
), pred.oth = c(0.040860431, 0.072931231, 0.0175463, 0.080798514, 
0.003179566, 0.108982246, 0.080770461, 0.028205698, 0.085832686, 
0.061340015)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(VoterID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), surname = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), state = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), CD = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), county = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), tract = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), block = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), sex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), party = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), PID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), place = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), pred.whi = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), pred.bla = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), pred.his = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), pred.asi = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), pred.oth = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Can you include a version of test.csv for us to copy-paste with dput()? Some fake data is fine if confidential or proprietary.

John - Unsure how to do that.  The data is not confidential, and is located here: https://github.com/kosukeimai/wru/blob/main/README.md

The data linked from the Github repo uses the built-in voters dataset that comes with the wru package. Since predict_race(voter.file = voters, census.geo = "tract") works fine, this means something your Voterfile  object (which originates from test.csv) is likely the source of the error. We can't help identify what that is unless we have test.csv. Run dput(head(Voterfile, n = 10)), copy the results and paste them into your question by editing it. Also see how to make a reproducible example.

Have you tried converting your county FIPS codes to characters? They should be 3 characters long with leading zeros, e.g., instead of 1 for DC, it should be 001. The predict_race() function calls get_census_data() internally, and when calling that function directly, it returns the same Error in tmp[[1]] : subscript out of bounds. But it successfully returns census tract data when the county codes use leading zeros (e.g., 001, 021, 061).
